# Lucene multi word tokens with delimiter

Tags: java, lucene, token, analyzer

I am just starting with Lucene so it's probably a beginners question. We are trying to implement a semantic search on digital books and already have a concept generator, so for example the contexts I generate for a new article could be:
|Green Beans | Spring Onions | Cooking |
I am using Lucene to create an index on the books/articles using only the extracted concepts (stored in a temporary document for that purpose). Now the standard analyzer is creating single word tokens: Green, Beans, Spring, Onions, Cooking, which of course is not the same.

My question: is there an analyzer that is able to detect delimiters around tokens (|| in our example), or an analyzer that is able to detect multi-word constructs?

I'm afraid we'll have to create our own analyzer, but I don't quite know where to start for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an analyzer is pretty easy. An analyzer is just a tokenizer optionally followed by token filters. In your case, you'd have to create your own tokenizer. Fortunately, you have a convenient base class for this: [`CharTokenizer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/CharTokenizer.html).

You implement the `isTokenChar` method and make sure it returns `false` on the `|` character and `true` on any other character. Everything else will be considered part of a token.

Once you have the tokenizer, the analyzer should be straightforward, just look at the source code of any existing analyzer and do likewise.

Oh, and if you can have spaces between your `|` chars, just add a [`TrimFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/TrimFilter.html) to the analyzer.

Comment: Hi, yeah I was afraid we'd have to that. I was just looking at org.apache.lucene.analysis.pattern and it seems they already provide a tokenizer based on regex = (|[^|]+|) in our case. I guess we should use that tokenizer and build our own analyzer on top of it.

Comment: Basing your tokenizer on `CharTokenizer` would be faster, but if you want to use the `PatternTokenizer` I'd suggest the following regex: pattern = `\s*\|\s*` with group = -1. This will split the input string on the regex, which will trim your tokens in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I am doing something with my Lucene mechanisms which creates data structures to do with sequencing, in effect "hijacking" the Lucene classes.  Otherwise I can't imagine why people would want knowledge of the separators ("delimiters") between tokens, but as it was quite tricky I thought I'd put it here for the benefit of anyone who might need to.

You have to rewrite your own versions of `StandardTokenizer` and `StandardTokenizerImpl`.  These are both `final` classes so you can't extend them.

**SeparatorDeliveringTokeniserImpl** (tweaked from source of `StandardTokenizerImpl`):

3 new fields:

```
private int startSepPos = 0;
private int endSepPos = 0;
private String originalBufferAsString;
```

Tweak these methods:

```
public final void getText(CharTermAttribute t) {
    t.copyBuffer(zzBuffer, zzStartRead, zzMarkedPos - zzStartRead);
    if( originalBufferAsString == null ){
        originalBufferAsString = new String( zzBuffer, 0, zzBuffer.length );
    }
    // startSepPos == -1 is a "flag condition": it means that this token is the last one and it won't be followed by a sep
    if( startSepPos != -1 ){
        // if the flag is NOT set, record the start pos of the next sep...
        startSepPos = zzMarkedPos;
    }
}

public final void yyreset(java.io.Reader reader) {
    zzReader = reader;
    zzAtBOL = true;
    zzAtEOF = false;
    zzEOFDone = false;
    zzEndRead = zzStartRead = 0;
    zzCurrentPos = zzMarkedPos = 0;
    zzFinalHighSurrogate = 0;
    yyline = yychar = yycolumn = 0;
    zzLexicalState = YYINITIAL;
    if (zzBuffer.length > ZZ_BUFFERSIZE)
        zzBuffer = new char[ZZ_BUFFERSIZE];
    // reset fields responsible for delivering separator...
    originalBufferAsString = null;
    startSepPos = 0;
    endSepPos = 0;
}
```

(inside `getNextToken`:)

```
if ((zzAttributes & 1) == 1) {
    zzAction = zzState;
    zzMarkedPosL = zzCurrentPosL;
    if ((zzAttributes & 8) == 8) {
        // every occurrence of a separator char leads here...
        endSepPos = zzCurrentPosL;
        break zzForAction;
    }
}
```

And make a new method:

```
String getPrecedingSeparator() {
    String sep = null;
    if( originalBufferAsString == null ){
        sep = new String( zzBuffer, 0, endSepPos );
    }
    else if( startSepPos == -1 || endSepPos <= startSepPos ){
        sep = "";
    }
    else {
        sep = originalBufferAsString.substring( startSepPos, endSepPos );
    }
    if( zzMarkedPos < startSepPos ){
        // ... then this is a sign that the next token will be the last one... and will NOT have a trailing separator
        // so set a "flag condition" for next time this method is called
        startSepPos = -1;
    }
    return sep;
}
```

**SeparatorDeliveringTokeniser** (tweaked from source of `StandardTokenizer`):

Add this:

```
private String separator;
String getSeparator(){
    // normally this delivers a preceding separator... but after incrementToken returns false, if there is a trailing
    // separator, it then delivers that...
    return separator;
}
```

(inside `incrementToken`:)

```
while(true) {
  int tokenType = scanner.getNextToken();

  // added NB this gives you the separator which PRECEDES the token
  // which you are about to get from scanner.getText( ... )
  separator = scanner.getPrecedingSeparator();

  if (tokenType == SeparatorDeliveringTokeniserImpl.YYEOF) {
      // NB at this point sep is equal to the trailing separator...
    return false;
  }
  ...
```

**Usage**:

In my `FilteringTokenFilter` subclass, called `TokenAndSeparatorExamineFilter`, the methods `accept` and `end` look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean accept() throws IOException {
    String sep = ((SeparatorDeliveringTokeniser) input).getSeparator();
    // a preceding separator can only be an empty String if we are currently 
    // dealing with the first token and if the sequence starts with a token 
    if (!sep.isEmpty()) {
       // ... do something with the preceding separator
    }
    // then get the token...
    String token = getTerm();
    // ... do something with the token

    // my filter does no filtering! Every token is accepted...:
    return true;
}

@Override
public void end() throws IOException {
    // deals with trailing separator at the end of a sequence of tokens and separators (if there is one, i.e. if it doesn't end with a token)
    String sep = ((SeparatorDeliveringTokeniser) input).getSeparator();
    // NB will be an empty String if there is no trailing separator
    if (!sep.isEmpty()) {
        // ... do something with this trailing separator
    }
}
```